# is there a method equal to hasOwnProperty() that can traverse prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, object, hasownproperty

for example i have an array , lets call it `myArray` where :

```
 var myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

even though , `myArray.join()` will return `'foo,bar'` , the check `myArray.hasOwnProperty('join')` , will return `false` , because simply `hasOwnProperty()` will not traverse the prototype chain.

Is there a way to do same function with ability to traverse the prototype chain?

P.S : even a custom method will do.

Comment: Yes, the `in` operator.

Comment: @elclanrs would you please clarify how exactly ?

Comment: if you know what you're looking for won't be false, null, 0, or "", if(myArray['join']) works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator.

> The in operator returns true for properties in the prototype chain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Like:

```
if ('join' in myArray) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: oh perfect , i didnt really think of that , after all it is an object !! thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine if a method or property is available within *either* the object or within the prototype chain for the object you can use the [**in** operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) as cited by elclanrs.

> > The in operator returns true for properties in the prototype chain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

In your example you could write-

```
if ('join' in myArray) { // do something }
```

If you want to determine the type of a property within the prototype chain then you can also use the [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). I can't find a "plain English" citation that this works with prototype operators, but if you type the following in the console of the dev tools of your choice-

```
var myArray = ['foo', 'bar']; typeof(myArray.join);
```

This will return "function" as expected, demonstrating that this operator does function with prototype functions and properties - and this is something I can also attest to from my experience. The typeof operator will return one of-

> > "undefined", "object", "boolean", "number", "string"

Comment: this is a typical answer like elclanrs

Comment: @ProllyGeek I cited elclanrs comment in my answer - but at the time I started writing the answer elclanrs had not posted an answer and you had requested further clarification, which I was attempting to provide. Although we have quoted from the same source, this was not a copy and paste answer.